# Why are loaders read from right to left in webpack?

Tags: webpack

In webpack, when loaders are applied to some files such as:

```
require("style-loader!css-loader!less-loader!./my-styles.less");
```

they work from right to left.

As it seems odd to me, what is the technical reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because it follows the [pipeline concept in unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)), so output of one process becomes input of the next one. Since the intention is processing `my-styles.less` through less-loader first, they are written side by side separated by a pipe (i.e. *!*). It could have been implemented to allow `require("./my-styles.less!less-loader!css-loader!style-loader");` as well. There isn't any technical difficulty difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's important to note the difference between piping and composing. In *nix environments, you can pipe commands from left-to-right:

`cat file.txt | egrep cars > output.txt`

But in functional programming you can compose functions together and the functions will execute from right-to-left:

`var fn0 = compose(divide(2), add(3));`

`var fn1 = pipe(add(3), divide(2));`

fn0 and fn1 will have the same effects on their inputs. Both will first add 3 to their inputs and divide the output of that operation by 2. Since we naturally read from left-to-right, the compose conventions require some familiarizing.

It seems to me that Webpack is following the convention of composing versus piping as it's ordered right-to-left. Check out Ramda's docs for a technical specification:

piping: http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#pipe

composing: http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#compose